# A probable error in Stein & Shakarchi's C.A., concerning estimates of Weierstrass canonical factorsy

Tags: complex-analysis

I think I have found out a flaw the second part of lemma 5.2, Chapter 5 (page 148, I'm using the commonest Princeton university press version). The lemma illustrates two estimates of canonical factors.

For $k\in\Bbb N$, the canonical factor at $z$ is defined by 
$$E_k(z)=(1-z)\exp(z+\frac12z^2+\frac13z^3+\cdots+\frac1kz^k).$$

The second part of the lemma states that

> Whenever $|z|\ge1/2$, there exists a $c>0$ such that
>   $$|E_k(z)|\ge |1-z| \exp(-c|z|^k)$$

The key problem is, although the authors don't explicitly mention uniformity for $k$ here, judging from the following text, they DO need  a constant $c$ to make the result hold uniformly for *all* $k$.

But how would it even be possible? For instance, take $z=-1/2$, how should one find a constant $c$ such that 
$$|E_k(-1/2)|=\frac12\exp(-\frac12+\frac12\frac1{2^2}-\frac13\frac1{2^3}+\cdots+(-1)^k\frac1k\frac1{2^k})\ge \frac12\exp(-c(-\frac12)^k)$$
holds for *all* $k$? Isn't it absurd? (Easy calculation shows that the power in LHS is no more than $-1/4$, while in RHS it oscillates between positive and negative. )

Comment: Don't forget the modulus: $\exp (-c \lvert z\rvert^k)$. But regardless, you can't find a $c > 0$ that works for all $k$ simultaneously. I expect that they don't need that uniformity, and that they allow $c$ to depend on $k$.

Comment: @DanielFischer yeah. Should be modulus here. But anyway if uniformity doesn't hold, then there is a point that'd seem hard to explain in the following text. I'll check that again, though, for confirmation.

Comment: Well, I don't have the book, so I can't check whether they somewhere need $c$ to be independent of $k$. What point would be hard to explain?

Comment: @DanielFischer it's an estimate of a product of canonical factors, in which they seem to have used the same $c$ for each term. Anyway I'll go to check that again and try to manage without uniformity if possible.

Comment: @DanielFischer by the way, because I have previously spotted two confirmed errors when I was reading this book, it might be I'm becoming a bit over-sceptical about it...

Comment: For the record, I remember reading that section, and I was quite uncomfortable with the lack of information about which constants depend on what parameters. In the end, I checked explicitly all constants (in this lemma, for example, we can take $2/(k+1)$ for the first part and $2^k$ for the second), and I believe that they didn't need the uniformity after all.